# Attach jQuery inputmask to DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I'm using RobinHerbot's inputmask and can't seem to figure out how to attach it to DOM elements.  I've come across a couple "solutions," but none that work the way I'm creating the new fields.  I tried creating a function to attach it to newly added fields because I know the code won't work on DOMs in the document ready function, but that didn't prove to be helpful either.

Here's a jsfiddle example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hnj6ed1y/40/)

**JS**

```
var count_2 = 5;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        count_2 = count_2 + 2;
        $('#Table tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + 
            '<p class=\"null_temp\">' +
            '<input type=\"text\" name=\"temp' + count_2 + '\" id=\"temp' + count_2 + '\" placeholder=\"Time\" size=\"10\" maxlength=\"8\" value=\"\" class=\"total_time_regex\" />' +
            '</td></tr>');
    });

        $('.total_time_regex').inputmask('Regex', { 
            regex: "^([0-9]{1,4}:[0-5][0-9])$"
        });
});

$(function() {
    $('.total_time_regex').inputmask('Regex', { 
        regex: "^([-][0-9]{1,4}:[0-5][0-9])|([0-9]{1,4}:[0-5][0-9])$"
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table style="width: 70%" id="Table" name="Table">
    <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p class="null_temp">
                <input type="text" name="temp1" id="temp1" placeholder="Time" size="10" maxlength="8" value="" class="total_time_regex" />
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd" value="Add More" class="button" />
```

**CSS**

```
#Table {
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
#Table td, #Table th {
    font-size:1em;
    border:1px solid #98bf21;
    padding:3px 7px 2px 7px;
}
#Table th {
    font-size:1.4em;
    text-align:left;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:4px;
    background-color:#A7C942;
    color:#fff;
}
#Table tr.alt td {
    color:#000;
    background-color:#EAF2D3;
}
```

Truly appreciate the help as I'm still learning how to deal with DOM elements.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Since the inputs will be created dynamically, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Try placing the `inputmask` code inside your click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the `inputmask` function inside the `btn` click.

```
var count_2 = 5;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        count_2 = count_2 + 2;
        $('#Table tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + 
            '<p class=\"null_temp\">' +
            '<input type=\"text\" name=\"temp' + count_2 + '\" id=\"temp' + count_2 + '\" placeholder=\"Time\" size=\"10\" maxlength=\"8\" value=\"\" class=\"total_time_regex\" />' +
            '</td></tr>');

        $('.total_time_regex').inputmask('Regex', {             
            regex: "^([0-9]{1,4}:[0-5][0-9])$"
        });
    });


});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/hnj6ed1y/42/

Comment: You still need to call the inputmask constructor on load to enable the mask on the existing element. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/hnj6ed1y/39/

Answer (score 2):

You're only calling the input masking function once when the document is ready, which results in only the initially created time box having the mask applied to it. You'll also need to add it to every input that's added after the page loads. You can use the same jQuery call, it just has to be called from the click handler as well as on page load. I would suggest putting your mask initialization in a function, like this:

```
var count_2 = 5;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        count_2 = count_2 + 2;
        $('#Table tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + 
            '<p class=\"null_temp\">' +
            '<input type=\"text\" name=\"temp' + count_2 + '\" id=\"temp' + count_2 + '\" placeholder=\"Time\" size=\"10\" maxlength=\"8\" value=\"\" class=\"total_time_regex\" />' +
            '</td></tr>');
        addMask();
    });

    function addMask() {
        $('.total_time_regex').inputmask('Regex', { 
            regex: "^([0-9]{1,4}:[0-5][0-9])$"
        });
    }
    addMask();
});
```

Working demo link: https://jsfiddle.net/70kat20w/.